# How can I get WPF DataGrid Selected Cell Value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my C# wpf application i have taken a DataGrid which is bounded by a datatable from database.
All values are displayed in this DataGrid. But i want to get the selected cell value.

Here is my code which is bounded by datatable:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = datatable1.DefaultView;
```

Please give me a solution to find the cell value.
I have found selected index by following code:

```
dataGrid1.SelectedIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are editing a `DataGridTextColumn` cell...

Use `e` which is in the `dataGrid1_CellEditEnding`Event like so:

```
((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text
```

This will give you the typed text.

Answer (score 0):

basically you can do this:

```
        var cellInfos = dataGrid1.SelectedCells;

        foreach (DataGridCellInfo cellInfo in cellInfos)
        {
            if (cellInfo.IsValid)
            {
                // element will be your DataGridCell Content
                var element = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item); 

                if (element != null)
                {
                    var myCell = element.Parent as DataGridCell;
                }
            }
        }
```